# How to put the label of Android Compose TextField to the same horizontal axis as the text itself?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I am trying to build Android Jetpack Compose app.

The vertical direction is very expensive for my app and the expected texts for the TextField inputs are very short. So, there is no reason, why the label should be at the top of the input text.

My question is - is it possible to put the label in the horizontal axis at the left side of the text?

Comment: If you want a fix label just use a 2nd TextField not editable

Comment: Anatomy of the TextField https://material.io/components/text-fields#anatomy suggests that every item (label, both icons, text, warning and hint) has its own predefined place and most likely this arrangement can not be changed and is not supposed to be changed.

Comment: The Material design doesn't provide this case. You can simply use a Row with a Text+TextField, a Row with 2 TextFields, or you have to built a custom TextField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Text` and `TextField` in a `Row`.

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun LabelTextField() {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Label",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    horizontal = 16.dp,
                ),
        )
        TextField(
            value = "Text",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1F),
        )
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]